What is the max height my gambrel roof truss will sit at?

I'm building a 10x12 gambrel style shed in my back yard and my max shed height is regulated. I've found a good plan to use, but it doesn't show the truss height and i need it to figure my total shed height. What would be the height based on the shown measurements? If you could explain your work it'd be appreciated.
Thanks

This question is more appropriate for the home improvement SE.

There is insufficient information in the diagram to answer your question exactly, because the extent to which the lower rafters are sunk into the ground is not provided.  We are only told that the shed width is 10 feet, but we aren't given reference points for this measurement.  If we assume everything is built above ground level, then the maximum external height this structure would attain is approximately 66 inches.

The total vertical height from the bottom of the lower rafter to the apex of the gusset is $$l\sin\theta+l\cos\theta$$ where $l=50.5$ inches and $\theta=22.5^o$
So it’s $65.98…$ inches
